# Qt: When QTimer actually started?

Tags: qt, qtimer

When application calls `QTimer::start()` is it started immediately or will be started after current event processed ? In other words, should I use single-shot timer with time correction in case of long-time processing in its `timeout()` slot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer with certainty would require inspecting platform-specific code within Qt. That's a good sign that this is not something you should be depending on. Moreover, [`QTimer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qtimer.html#accuracy-and-timer-resolution) doesn't promise much in terms of accuracy:

> Timers will never time out earlier than the specified timeout value
>   and they are not guaranteed to time out at the exact value specified.
>   In many situations, they may time out late by a period of time that
>   depends on the accuracy of the system timers.
>
> The accuracy of timers depends on the underlying operating system and
>   hardware. Most platforms support a resolution of 1 millisecond, though
>   the accuracy of the timer will not equal this resolution in many
>   real-world situations.
>
> If Qt is unable to deliver the requested number of timer clicks, it
>   will silently discard some.

If you need to know precisely how much time has passed between timeout signals, use your `QTimer` in conjunction with a [`QElapsedTimer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qelapsedtimer.html).

Comment: I don't need high precision between consecutive timeouts (because it's not possible in non-realtime OS). I just need to keep average speed (i.e. eliminate growing drift). So, I still have to make use single-shots with correction by QElapsedTimer ?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, the average time between timeouts will be larger than the time specified.

Comment: Though, typically I would try to use `QTimer` solely for _triggering_ updates, and pass the elapsed time from `QElapsedTimer`  into my update function as the timestep. Depending on what you're doing, changing your update to take a timestep as an argument may or may not be possible, but if you can I'd recommend it.

Comment: OK, thank you. Actually it's the same with only difference that it's for post-processing rather than pre-processing (my case).